# JSON file to bootstrape table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I have a JSON file like this:

[image]

and want to convert to a bootstrape table :

[image]

can anyone help me?

Comment: Whatever you did so far, please put your code here.

Answer (score 0):

So this is a problem of `Array#groupBy` .

Then , you need :

### 0. Parse JSON data to be Javascript array :

```
 data=JSON.parse(data);
```

### 1. Get all columns headers (SaleA,Sale B ,....):

```
var cols=data.map((item)=>Object.keys(item).filter((k)=>k.indexOf('Sale')===0)[0]);
cols=[...new Set(cols)] // to avoid duplication of values
 // output: ["Sale A","Sale B","Sale C"]
```

### 2. Get all rows headers (date)

```
var rows=data.map((item)=>item.Date);
rows=[...new Set(rows)] // avoid duplication . 
 // out : ['2016-07-04','2016-07-05','2016-07-06']
```

### 3. Bind Data to HTML & Build Table :

```
 var thead=`<tr>
               <th>Date</th>
               ${cols.map((c)=>`<th>${c}</th>`).join('')}
           </tr>`  ; 
  var skeleton='<table>'+thead+cols.map((col)=>` <tr>
                                     ${rows.map((r)=>"<td></td>").join('')}
                                 </tr>"`).join('')+'</table>';
```

### 5. Fill this skelton by `data` Array :

- filtering on value of column & data

  ```
   function fill(skeleton,data){

          data.forEach(function(dt,index){

              // $(skeleton).find('....').html(dt);
               // -> Do it by yourself
         }); 
         return skeleton
   };
  ```

### 6. Append this table to Container :

```
$(fill(skeleton,data)).appendTo('body')
```